# Cleaining up objects with the __del__ method

Tags: python, python-2.7, destructor, resource-cleanup

I'm developing a python program to monitor and control a game-server. The game-server has many game-cores, and those cores handle the clients.

I have a python class called `Server` that holds instances of the class `Core`, and those instances are used to manage the actual game-cores. The `Core` class needs to connect to the game-core via TCP-Socket, in order to send commands to that specific game-core. To close those sockets properly, the `Core` class has a `__del__` method which closes the socket.

An example:

```
class Server(object):
    Cores = [] # list which will be filled with the Core objects
    def __init__(self):
        # detect the game-cores, create the core objects and append them to self.Cores

class Core(object):
    CoreSocket = None # when the socket gets created, the socket-object will be bound to this variable
    def __init__(self, coreID):
        # initiate the socket connection between the running game-core and this python object

    def __del__(self):
        # properly close the socket connection
```

Now, when I use the `Core` class itself, the destructor always gets called properly. But when I use the `Server` class, the `Core` objects inside `Server.Cores` **never get destructed.** I have read that the gc has a problem with circular references and classes with destructors, but the `Core` objects never reference the `Server` object (only the socket-object, in `Core.CoreSocket`), so no circular references are created.

I usually prefer using the `with`-statement for resource cleaning, but in this case I need to send commands over many different methods in the `Server` class, so using `with` won't help ... I also tried to create and close the socket on each command, but that really kills the performance when I need to send many commands. Weak refereneces created with the `weakref` module won't help eigther, because the destructors then get called immediately after I create the `Server` object.

Why don't the `Core` objects get destructed properly when the `Server` object gets cleaned up by the gc? I guess I'm just forgetting something simple, but I just can't find out what it is.

Or maybe there is a better approach for closing those sockets when the object gets cleaned up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've mixed up class and instance members. Unlike in some other languages, defining a variable at class scope creates a class variable, not an instance variable. When a `Server` instance dies, the `Server` class is still around and still holds references to the cores. Define `self.cores` in the `__init__` method instead:

```
class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cores = []
```

Comment: I'll try it right away! :)
Completely forgot about this, thank you!

Comment: Working as expected now!